# Problema com os Paths dos arquivos no meu projeto

Tags: visual-studio, path

Uma certa vez eu criei uma pasta e copiei todos os arquivos do meu projeto para ela, porém a partir disto o meu projeto original está com os caminhos `form1.cs`, `form1.designer.cs` e `form1.resx` especificados para a pasta cópia.

Não estou conseguindo voltar com as configurações originais, como eu altero o caminho dos arquivos para deixar tudo em uma única pasta?

**Nota**

> Tentei alterar pelas propriedades, porém fica bloqueado.

**LOCALIZAÇÃO DO ARQUIVO** `.sln`

```
D:\Felipe Pen Drive\arquivos...\Aplicativo...
```

**LOCALIZAÇÃO DOS ARQUIVOS** `form1.cs`, `form1.designer.cs` e `form1.resx`

```
D:\Felipe Pen Drive\copia
```

**CONFIGURAÇÃO DA PROPRIEDADE**

[image: caminho Form1.cs]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar os forms existentes (que estão na pasta correta) "de volta" ao projeto. Para isso, clique com o botão direito no projeto e vá em: Adicionar -> Item existente (Shift + Alt + A) e selecione os arquivos `form1.cs`, `form1.designer.cs` e `form1.resx`. O VS irá substituir automaticamente os caminhos desses itens em suas respectivas propriedades.